# Transform the columns into specific values, then include them as rows with their previous values

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have some columns with some values associated with them.
I want to give to each column (a and b) the values (1 and 2) and put them in the row.
Here is the code to better see the transformation:

```
#Create a dataframe, let's day a and b are the name of some brands
df = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6)) 

# I want to assign the numbers 1 and 2 to brand a and b
df1 = data.frame(brand=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

I need a function that automatically do this: Transform df into df1*

EDIT: For context, I'm doing this transformation for an Anova test

Comment: Try `stack(df)`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))

df1 <- gather(df, brand, value) %>% ## Convert columns into rows
  mutate(brand = as.numeric(as.factor(brand))) ## Convert a and b into 1 and 2
```